# How to delete files from Basecamp using their API?

Tags: api, rest, basecamp

I was able to successfully use the [Basecamp File API](http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/files.shtml) to get the list of the files in a project, and download files. But how can I delete files? Issuing a DELETE instead of a GET on the file doesn't seem to do the trick for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they don't expose an REST API method for DELETEing files.